# Swift - physicsBody curved decent, can't get right curviture

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a 2D game and I'm looking to direct a node in a particular clockwise curve from the sky to the ground (like a bird would swoop down to the ground) in a clockwise motion with some friction to give the effect of a bird landing.

I've been playing around with 'physicsBody' but i cant seem to get the right curve, can anyone help... here is a picture of the curve I'm trying to achieve.  http://www.theluxuryteam.com/uploads/shared/images/curved_arrow-black.png

Thank you

```
    func addCrow() {
        var crow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "crow")
        crow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: crow.size)
        crow.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        crow.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        crow.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -200, dy: 0)
        crow.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 100
        crow.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        crow.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 100
        var random : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(300))
        crow.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 1.4, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.2 ) //  1.4  0.8
        self.addChild(crow)

    }
```